# Is it possible to save the perl modules using cpanm?

Tags: perl, cpan

The following commands attempts to reinstall, I just want to download w/o installing. I'm usnig Ubuntu.

```
cpanm Test::Fatal --save-dists saved
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use cpanget (part of cpanspec).Or, cpan -g module module.

While I hail from a RH platform, ultimately both command  come from the CPAN archive and  "cpan" in particular - from the CPAN distribution, should be totally platform agnostic, and comes to a little more of

`use App::Cpan; my $rc = App::Cpan->run( @ARGV ); exit $rc;`

Comment: Is that a RH thing? I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: Edited above...

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
cpanm --test-only --notest Test::Fatal
```

and then look into '~/.cpanm/latest-build/', here should be all sources used in last build process.